# AttributeError when using numpy.logical_and with Pandas Series object

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm confused about the difference between Pandas Series objects when using `reindex_like` and related features.  For example, consider the following Series objects:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import pandas
>>> series = pandas.Series([1, 2, 3])
>>> x = pandas.Series([True]).reindex_like(series).fillna(True)
>>> y = pandas.Series(True, index=series.index)
>>> x
0    True
1    True
2    True
>>> y
0    True
1    True
2    True
```

On the surface `x` and `y` appear to be identical in their contents and indexing.  However, they must be different in some way because one of them causes an error when using `numpy.logical_and()` and the other does not.

```
>>> numpy.logical_and(series, y)
0    True
1    True
2    True
>>> numpy.logical_and(series, x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-10-e2050a2015bf>", line 1, in <module>
    numpy.logical_and(series, x)
AttributeError: logical_and
```

What is `numpy.logical()` and complaining about here?  I don't see the difference between the two series, `x` and `y`.  However, there must be some subtle difference.

The Pandas documentation says the Series object is a valid argument to "most NumPy functions."  Clearly this is true somewhat in this case.  Apparently the creation mechanism makes `x` unusable to this particular numpy function.

As a side-note, which of the two creation mechanisms, `reindex_like()` and the `index` argument are more efficient and idiomatic for this scenario?  Maybe there is another/better way I haven't considered also.

Comment: Which pandas/numpy/python version are you using? `numpy.logical_and(series, x)` works without error for me in `pandas-0.9.0-py2.7`...

Comment: Using pandas 0.9.1 and numpy 1.6.2

Comment: I would be surprised if this is a new bug in pandas 0.9.1, but perhaps worth upgrading to numpy version 1.8? (the version I am using which seems to work...)

Comment: The current stable release of numpy is 1.6.2 (via PyPi and numpy site).  Are you using the github repo of numpy for version 1.8?  I think I'll post a github issue for pandas and see what they say.

Comment: I posted an issue on github for Pandas.  Maybe they will have more insight: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2388

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is not a bug and the subtle difference is due to the usage of the `reindex_like()` method.  The call to `reindex_like()` inserts some NaN data into the series so the `dtype` of that series changes from `bool` to `object`.

```
>>> series = pandas.Series([1, 2, 3])
>>> x = pandas.Series([True])
>>> x.dtype
dtype('bool')
>>> x = pandas.Series([True]).reindex_like(series)
>>> x.dtype
dtype('object')
```

I posted an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2388) about this anomaly on the Pandas github page.

The full explanation/discussion is [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2388#issuecomment-10858926).  It looks like this behavior could potentially change in the future so watch the [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2388) for more on-going details.